# "Go To Definition" is greyed out but I can find variable via search in same file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

I'm debugging c# good in vs2008 SP1, .NET Framework 3.5.

In a .cs file, I have this code:

```
internal protected bool Refreshing{  
        get { return refreshing;}  
        set { refreshing = value;}  
}
```

elsewhere, in the same file, I have this statement:

```
if (Refreshing) return;
```

When I am debugging and right click "Refreshing",
"Go To Definition" is greyed out.

It's not just properties for which "Go To Definition" is greyed out;
it's methods too and probably everything else.

It seems to be "Go To Definition" is especially useful
during debugging; more so than when just looking at code.

Any ideas why?

Comment: What are the project settings for the version you are debugging?  For example, is the Debugging element defined so that there is a corresponding pdb file?

Comment: Yes, the file has a corresponding .pdb file.
Since I can debug through all of the code, I'm guessing the project settings are correct (I could be wrong).